# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Maven Project

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project in the following structure.

```
TestRun
|
|--src/main/java/com/main/CallAddNumbers.java (Package - Com.main)
|
|--src/test/java/com/test/RunTest.java (package com.test)
```

and here is the sample program

```
package com.main;    
public class CallAddNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.test.AddNumbers.addNumbers(5, 4);
    }   
}

package com.test;

public class AddNumbers {   
    public static void addNumbers (int a, int b){   
        System.out.println(a+b);        
    }
}
```

When I am calling addNumbers method from main, I am ending up with the following error. May be something simple, but can't figure it out.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/RunTest
    at com.main.CallAddNumbers.main(CallAddNumbers.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.RunTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using classes in your test package from your production code? Test classes are deliberately not compiled when running an application in most cases. Anyway, is src/test in your source build path?

Comment: @Ordus, This is a simple test project to demonstrate the problem. "is src/test in your source build path?" NO

Comment: Well then how do you expect it to compile if you are trying to use a class that's not on the build path?

Answer (score 0):

you said it might be something simple, just wanted to check that this is your actual file structure before looking any further!

```
|
|--src/main/java/com/main/CallAddNumbers.java (Package - com.main)
|
|--src/test/java/com/test/addNumbers.java (package com.test)
```

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct. The actual file structure is like you mentioned. Corrected in my question. Thanks you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this import statement to the `CallAddNumbers` class

```
import test.java.com.test.AddNumbers;
```

It will work fine. Btw better dont write production codes in test package